# How can i login without permission dialog on facebook with ios sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, permissions, dialog

in my application on iphone when i call

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

the framework show login dialog automatically if i'm not loggedin, and then show permission dialog (This is great for the frist time that a user use the application).
But if i've aleady get permission i always show the dialog with message "You have aleady authorized this application". 
So, how can i login without show permission dialog? Or can i check if i've aleady get permission to the application?
In the framework sample code the only way to login is by authorize method...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the Access Token (make sure to request offline_access permission) locally on the device and next time the user uses your App check if the token's still active (make a call to /me/permissions or something like that ) - if it is still active you don't need to go back to Facebook to reauthenticate- if it isn't, the current Login code you're using should still be fine.